# Select ttl using querybuilder in cassandra

Tags: cassandra, query-builder, cassandra-2.0

I am trying to execute a statement using query builder. The query can be 
executed in cqlsh.How can I do it? TIA.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to use `fcall` together with `column`? Something like:

```
QueryBuilder.select().fcall("ttl", QueryBuilder.column("c"))...
```

Or you can use the `ttl` function of `Select.Selection` class directly as:

```
QueryBuilder.select().column("a").ttl("c").from(...)...
```

See [documentation on this class](https://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/2.0/com/datastax/driver/core/querybuilder/Select.Selection.html).

Comment: Yes that works. But I want to select ttl of column c and column a both using one preparedStatement. TIA.